# Firebase Multi-Language support: Is possible?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to have a multilanguage json file for Firebase Database?

**Example:** 
I have the following in json file:

```
"219" : {
      "AnswerA" : "Monarchy",
      "AnswerB" : "Aristocracy",
      "AnswerC" : "Theocracy",
      "AnswerD" : "Anarchy",
      "CategoryID" : "01",
      "CorrectAnswer" : "Theocracy",
      "IsImageQuestion" : "false",
      "Question" : "What is the type of Government in Swaziland?"
    },
```

How can i add a translation, so when user choose another language, get the question and answer in the new language?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Firebase Multi-Language support: Is possible?

Yes, it is but with some changes in your database structure. A possible multi-language structure for your use-case might be:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- questions
          |
          --- en
          |    |
          |    --- 219
          |         |
          |         --- //English values for your properties
          |
          --- fr
               |
               --- 219
                    |
                    --- //French values for your properties
```

Using this structure, you can simply switch the language in the moment when the user chooses another language. The reference for an english question is:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference enQuestionIdRef = rootRef.child("questions").child("en").child("219");
```

While for the french version, a single simple change must be made:

```
DatabaseReference enQuestionIdRef = rootRef.child("questions").child("fr").child("219");
```

Comment: Terrible solution: u need to store data objects dupes for all the languages instead of arranging land specific data in ONE data object.