# Flitter Firebase multi language

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm developing an application using Flutter and Firebase.
I need to support multiple languages and I was wondering about what is the best solution to do that... Can I keep the strings in Firebase and fetch them without downloading them each time I need?
When the user select a language the first, usually it does not change, but sometimes it could.
Thanks!

Comment: I also need to be able to add new strings without updating the application through the stores...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't understand why you want to use multi-languages feature using Firebase.
In any app at least there are static texts.So at least for that part you don't need the translation stored in the Firebase (performance issue). I suggest to have a look at this package `easy_localization` : https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization
Why you should use static translation:
when using non static translation (downloaded from Firebase) :

- You have to download the translations : App does work only if connected to network (at least first time or after user clear the cache of the application)
- You have to cache the result : using shared_preferences
- You have to fetch the translations from cache every time.
  If you still insist about using Firebase.You can see a similar question for android (answered by GDE): [Firebase Multi-Language support: Is possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55435343/firebase-multi-language-support-is-possible)

Comment: That's fine. Thank you!